# Billing form - Request for more information if entered data match with a number

Tags: php, regex

can you help me? I'm trying to create a billing info form, and if the customer enter an example `5120293213632438` I'll use 'substr' to get the first 6 numbers, if those 6 numbers match with `512029`, `537030`, `432049`, etc... I'll request for more info -> VAT number and ID.

```
<form action="validate.php" method="post">
  <p>Credit Card Number : <input type="text" name="cc" /></p>
  <p><input type="submit" value="Next"></p>
</form>
```

validate.php

```
<?php
$vbv = substr($_POST['cc'], 6);
if($vbv == '512029')
    $flag = strstr($bin, $needle);
    echo "OK";
else 
    echo "I'm not VBV";
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$array=array(512029, 537030, 432049);  //array of start 6 digits you want  to match

$cc='5120293213632438';//credit card no's you want to match.

if(in_array(substr($cc, 0,6),$array))
{
    echo "First 6 digit matched";
}
```

Comment: Amazing! Thank you so much, its works ! Can I create more arrays for other bins (Visa, MC, Amex ..etc) witht the same code? How can I integrate more arrays?

Comment: @ArturoDT You can add more values to the array it will work fine. Hope you will accept my answer